# Inbound emails using webhook with Mandrill Ruby

Tags: ruby

According to the documentation, we should be looking at a parameter called "message", which doesn't not come in. What does come in is a parameter called "mandrill_events".

```
require 'mail'

class InboxController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create

  def create
    mail = Mail.new(params[:message])
....
```

No dice, but I do see this in the console log when I use the following syntax (note, it's so much JSON that SO has trouble viewing it with formatting):

```
puts JSON.parse(params[:mandrill_events])

{"mandrill_events"=>"[{\"event\":\"inbound\",\"ts\":1426188360,\"msg\":{\"raw_msg\":\"Received: from mail-ob0-f181.google.com (unknown [209.85.214.181])\\n\\tby ip-10-39-136-77 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 25B0E2C0509\\n\\tfor <test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 19:26:00 +0000 (UTC)\\nReceived: by obcvb8 with SMTP id vb8so16123307obc.10\\n        for <test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\\/relaxed;\\n        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;\\n        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;\\n        bh=jyd6a9aMNBrnuDpbsOEokXnACKw\\/lLnh72zkG7LCs3c=;\\n        b=wzt6xiplBtL6dq7uGR8RV6tRR9Lcsmj5zmIktZ7KXFcxbwezN+uEhK\\/XFw6ZjIfhp6\\n         LVoEH5ljLjOwK4X4nrtHaPoNzHZizwQUzxk0qXGabTXHW6tqOLZUs3FeDwtt2ekeLvlb\\n         bDuU4VcBnNZ5VkXDpA5hQeysCfGECBilAtMy\\/EBjdOngcgk4Fsp8u11\\/eeB2xqBPUcrR\\n         JYeu\\/99XossdoeJW3avfxFDBw7ngc98oRS2ZPpyL7MY36XoCZCM25U9ue9kBcJ82n92i\\n         ctbNdl+9ikVPdcmUokI0WIvBIBGl5yAcrvOQffxmaTz0c31fkq8+iyprDMP\\/GexVfQzN\\n         SAKA==\\nMIME-Version: 1.0\\nX-Received: by 10.202.89.135 with SMTP id n129mr34093639oib.60.1426188359432;\\n Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\\nReceived: by 10.60.119.68 with HTTP; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\\nDate: Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700\\nMessage-ID: <CAMf1_47jvgW6QMwDx8R9JU6C5YiUMaPjvFz3muxhM5v4HJyoSg@mail.gmail.com>\\nSubject: Subject FTW?\\nFrom: Dee diabetic <Deediabetic@gmail.com>\\nTo: test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com\\nContent-Type: multipart\\/alternative; boundary=001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\\n\\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\\nContent-Type: text\\/plain; charset=UTF-8\\n\\nBody here\\n\\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\\nContent-Type: text\\/html; charset=UTF-8\\n\\n<div dir=\\\"ltr\\\">Body here<\\/div>\\n\\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88--\",\"headers\":{\"Received\":[\"from mail-ob0-f181.google.com (unknown [209.85.214.181]) by ip-10-39-136-77 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 25B0E2C0509 for <test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 19:26:00 +0000 (UTC)\",\"by obcvb8 with SMTP id vb8so16123307obc.10 for <test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com>; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\",\"by 10.60.119.68 with HTTP; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\"],\"Dkim-Signature\":\"v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed\\/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type; bh=jyd6a9aMNBrnuDpbsOEokXnACKw\\/lLnh72zkG7LCs3c=; b=wzt6xiplBtL6dq7uGR8RV6tRR9Lcsmj5zmIktZ7KXFcxbwezN+uEhK\\/XFw6ZjIfhp6 LVoEH5ljLjOwK4X4nrtHaPoNzHZizwQUzxk0qXGabTXHW6tqOLZUs3FeDwtt2ekeLvlb bDuU4VcBnNZ5VkXDpA5hQeysCfGECBilAtMy\\/EBjdOngcgk4Fsp8u11\\/eeB2xqBPUcrR JYeu\\/99XossdoeJW3avfxFDBw7ngc98oRS2ZPpyL7MY36XoCZCM25U9ue9kBcJ82n92i ctbNdl+9ikVPdcmUokI0WIvBIBGl5yAcrvOQffxmaTz0c31fkq8+iyprDMP\\/GexVfQzN SAKA==\",\"Mime-Version\":\"1.0\",\"X-Received\":\"by 10.202.89.135 with SMTP id n129mr34093639oib.60.1426188359432; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\",\"Date\":\"Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700\",\"Message-Id\":\"<CAMf1_47jvgW6QMwDx8R9JU6C5YiUMaPjvFz3muxhM5v4HJyoSg@mail.gmail.com>\",\"Subject\":\"Subject FTW?\",\"From\":\"Dee diabetic <Deediabetic@gmail.com>\",\"To\":\"test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com\",\"Content-Type\":\"multipart\\/alternative; boundary=001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\"},\"text\":\"Body here\\n\\n\",\"text_flowed\":false,\"html\":\"<div dir=\\\"ltr\\\">Body here<\\/div>\\n\\n\",\"from_email\":\"Deediabetic@gmail.com\",\"from_name\":\"Dee diabetic\",\"to\":[[\"test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com\",null]],\"subject\":\"Subject FTW?\",\"spf\":{\"result\":\"pass\",\"detail\":\"sender SPF authorized\"},\"spam_report\":{\"score\":0.5,\"matched_rules\":[{\"name\":\"RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW\",\"score\":-0.7,\"description\":\"RBL: Sender listed at http:\\/\\/www.dnswl.org\\/, low\"},{\"name\":null,\"score\":0,\"description\":null},{\"name\":\"listed\",\"score\":0,\"description\":\"in list.dnswl.org]\"},{\"name\":\"FREEMAIL_FROM\",\"score\":0,\"description\":\"Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider\"},{\"name\":\"HTML_MESSAGE\",\"score\":0,\"description\":\"BODY: HTML included in message\"},{\"name\":\"DKIM_VALID_AU\",\"score\":-0.1,\"description\":\"Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's\"},{\"name\":\"DKIM_SIGNED\",\"score\":0.1,\"description\":\"Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid\"},{\"name\":\"DKIM_VALID\",\"score\":-0.1,\"description\":\"Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature\"},{\"name\":\"RDNS_NONE\",\"score\":1.3,\"description\":\"Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS\"}]},\"dkim\":{\"signed\":true,\"valid\":true},\"email\":\"test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com\",\"tags\":[],\"sender\":null,\"template\":null}}]"}
```

Mar 12 12:26:046666 app/web.1:  {"event"=>"inbound", "ts"=>1426188360, "msg"=>{"raw_msg"=>"Received: from mail-ob0-f181.google.com (unknown [209.85.214.181])\n\tby ip-10-39-136-77 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 25B0E2C0509\n\tfor ; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 19:26:00 +0000 (UTC)\nReceived: by obcvb8 with SMTP id vb8so16123307obc.10\n        for ; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\nDKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;\n        d=gmail.com; s=20120113;\n        h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;\n        bh=jyd6a9aMNBrnuDpbsOEokXnACKw/lLnh72zkG7LCs3c=;\n        b=wzt6xiplBtL6dq7uGR8RV6tRR9Lcsmj5zmIktZ7KXFcxbwezN+uEhK/XFw6ZjIfhp6\n         LVoEH5ljLjOwK4X4nrtHaPoNzHZizwQUzxk0qXGabTXHW6tqOLZUs3FeDwtt2ekeLvlb\n         bDuU4VcBnNZ5VkXDpA5hQeysCfGECBilAtMy/EBjdOngcgk4Fsp8u11/eeB2xqBPUcrR\n         JYeu/99XossdoeJW3avfxFDBw7ngc98oRS2ZPpyL7MY36XoCZCM25U9ue9kBcJ82n92i\n         ctbNdl+9ikVPdcmUokI0WIvBIBGl5yAcrvOQffxmaTz0c31fkq8+iyprDMP/GexVfQzN\n         SAKA==\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nX-Received: by 10.202.89.135 with SMTP id n129mr34093639oib.60.1426188359432;\n Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\nReceived: by 10.60.119.68 with HTTP; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)\nDate: Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700\nMessage-ID: \nSubject: Subject FTW?\nFrom: Dee diabetic \nTo: test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\n\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\nContent-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n\nBody here\n\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\n\nBody here\n\n--001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88--", "headers"=>{"Received"=>["from mail-ob0-f181.google.com (unknown [209.85.214.181]) by ip-10-39-136-77 (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 25B0E2C0509 for ; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 19:26:00 +0000 (UTC)", "by obcvb8 with SMTP id vb8so16123307obc.10 for ; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)", "by 10.60.119.68 with HTTP; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)"], "Dkim-Signature"=>"v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20120113; h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type; bh=jyd6a9aMNBrnuDpbsOEokXnACKw/lLnh72zkG7LCs3c=; b=wzt6xiplBtL6dq7uGR8RV6tRR9Lcsmj5zmIktZ7KXFcxbwezN+uEhK/XFw6ZjIfhp6 LVoEH5ljLjOwK4X4nrtHaPoNzHZizwQUzxk0qXGabTXHW6tqOLZUs3FeDwtt2ekeLvlb bDuU4VcBnNZ5VkXDpA5hQeysCfGECBilAtMy/EBjdOngcgk4Fsp8u11/eeB2xqBPUcrR JYeu/99XossdoeJW3avfxFDBw7ngc98oRS2ZPpyL7MY36XoCZCM25U9ue9kBcJ82n92i ctbNdl+9ikVPdcmUokI0WIvBIBGl5yAcrvOQffxmaTz0c31fkq8+iyprDMP/GexVfQzN SAKA==", "Mime-Version"=>"1.0", "X-Received"=>"by 10.202.89.135 with SMTP id n129mr34093639oib.60.1426188359432; Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700 (PDT)", "Date"=>"Thu, 12 Mar 2015 12:25:59 -0700", "Message-Id"=>"", "Subject"=>"Subject FTW?", "From"=>"Dee diabetic ", "To"=>"test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com", "Content-Type"=>"multipart/alternative; boundary=001a113d39288bfe8505111c5a88"}, "text"=>"Body here\n\n", "text_flowed"=>false, "html"=>"Body here\n\n", "from_email"=>"Deediabetic@gmail.com", "from_name"=>"Dee diabetic", "to"=>[["test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com", nil]], "subject"=>"Subject FTW?", "spf"=>{"result"=>"pass", "detail"=>"sender SPF authorized"}, "spam_report"=>{"score"=>0.5, "matched_rules"=>[{"name"=>"RCVD_IN_DNSWL_LOW", "score"=>-0.7, "description"=>"RBL: Sender listed at http://www.dnswl.org/, low"}, {"name"=>nil, "score"=>0, "description"=>nil}, {"name"=>"listed", "score"=>0, "description"=>"in list.dnswl.org]"}, {"name"=>"FREEMAIL_FROM", "score"=>0, "description"=>"Sender email is commonly abused enduser mail provider"}, {"name"=>"HTML_MESSAGE", "score"=>0, "description"=>"BODY: HTML included in message"}, {"name"=>"DKIM_VALID_AU", "score"=>-0.1, "description"=>"Message has a valid DKIM or DK signature from author's"}, {"name"=>"DKIM_SIGNED", "score"=>0.1, "description"=>"Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid"}, {"name"=>"DKIM_VALID", "score"=>-0.1, "description"=>"Message has at least one valid DKIM or DK signature"}, {"name"=>"RDNS_NONE", "score"=>1.3, "description"=>"Delivered to internal network by a host with no rDNS"}]}, "dkim"=>{"signed"=>true, "valid"=>true}, "email"=>"test@inbound.diabetesdelivery.com", "tags"=>[], "sender"=>nil, "template"=>nil}}

So I am getting a JSON string, but how exactly is the best way to grab the TO, FROM, and SUBJECT?

Update: I just tried the following:

```
tester =  JSON.parse(params[:mandrill_events])

puts tester[:msg][:subject]

#and even this

puts tester["msg"]["subject"]
```

Did not work. Got an error: **TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer): **

Answer (score 0):

After a day of banging my head, I came up with the solution. By the way, accessing the values directly doesn't work. I had to loop into it.

```
incomingMail = params[:mandrill_events]

mail_from = "Cannot read From"
mail_originally_to = "Cannot read To"
mail_subject = "No subject"
mail_date = ""
mail_body = "No email body"

if incomingMail != nil
  incomingMail = JSON.parse(incomingMail)

  incomingMail.each do |item|
    mail_from = item["msg"]["from_email"]
    mail_originally_to = item["msg"]["headers"]["To"]
    mail_subject = item["msg"]["subject"]
    mail_date = item["msg"]["headers"]["Date"]
    mail_body = item["msg"]["text"]
    mail_body_html = item["msg"]["html"]
  end

  #Confirm
else
  puts "Email not sent. Parameter invalid."
end
```